# WCF RESTful Service returning null all the time

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a WCF RESTful Service method as follows with Id as 101 and 102

```
public EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id)
    {
        List<EmployeeJSON> employees = new List<EmployeeJSON>()
        {
             new EmployeeJSON() {Name="Sumanth",Id=101,Salary=5000.00 },
             new EmployeeJSON() {Name="Ehsan",Id=102,Salary=6000.00 },
        };

        var Employee = (from x in employees
                        where x.Id.ToString() == id
                        select x);


        return Employee as EmployeeJSON;
    }
```

At any point of time, for the passed Id value, I will get 1 record from client

The declaration is as follows

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetJson/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id);
```

The client code is given below

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1249/Service1.svc/GetJson/101");
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        txtEmpId.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

And for 101 and 102 and any parameter value say 100, it is always returning error as follows

```
{"GetEmployeeJSONResult":null}
```

Could not figure out why...

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suggest you to check what your LINQ query returns. I think it is List<EmployeeJSON> after all.

Comment: LINQ query returns one EmployeeJSON record. But after coming out of it, it is returning null.

Comment: It returns one only because you have one record with the specified Id. If you had 2 or more records, it would return all of them. No mater how many you have that LINQ query should return List<EmployeeJSON>. You need to explicitly say that you need only first record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this function `public EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id)` the return type is changed as below and it worked

```
return Employee.FirstOrDefault() as EmployeeJSON;
```

Comment: I usually use lambdas with LINQ, so I was not sure if it was the thing, but I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: Why do you have `as EmployeeJSON`? And why not simply `return employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.ToString() == id)`? And why are you accepting a string if the ID is really an int? Why not change the type to match throughout your code and eliminate the redundant `.ToString()`?